# Created a delete function that doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a little project where i'm creating a delete function that should delete a so called "exercise block". These blocks have IDs which get incremented.
the problem: The function doesn't seem to work (most likely my own fault, i'm new to javascript / jquery).

What I would like to be able to do: when I click on the button it should take away the eBlock with incremented number, so basically it should only target its parent element.

a fiddle for you to try it urself. i'm talking about the red button with an X in it. not the one with the minus sign. You guys will most likely find it out urself, but to spare u some time and confusion: You first have to click on the green + button so a whole new block pops up. https://jsfiddle.net/DanDy/sa2eowhh/4/

all the related code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success',
    'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
    $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select();
    id++;
    exerciseAudioInput++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

  $('form').append(addOpdracht);
  $('form').append(getExerciseTitle());
});


function getRemoveBtnExercise(target, i){
  var RemoveExerciseBtn = $('<a/>', {
  'class': 'btn btn-danger'
 }).on('click', function(){           
   let exerciseInputs = exerciseInputs[exerciseInputs.length-1].remove(target);
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');

return RemoveExerciseBtn;
}


 //the block where the fields get append to.
  function getExerciseBlock(i){
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
    'id': i,
    'class': 'col-md-12 eBlock'
  });

 $(eBlock).append(getRemoveBtnExercise(i), getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), 
getWordPartInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), getRemoveBtn(i), getAddBtn(eBlock, 
i));

  return eBlock;
}
```

the code that creates the button that should delete a block:

```
function getRemoveBtnExercise(target, i){
  var RemoveExerciseBtn = $('<a/>', {
  'class': 'btn btn-danger'
 }).on('click', function(){           
   let exerciseInputs = exerciseInputs[exerciseInputs.length-1].remove(target);
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');

return RemoveExerciseBtn;
}
```

with kind regards,

Comment: You can look in the console to see any errors you might have like `Uncaught ReferenceError: exerciseInputs is not defined`

Comment: That's exactly the error i'm having lol.. I mean, EXACTLY what u wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable *exerciseInputs* was not defined, however I have updated your code.

***From***

`let exerciseInputs = exerciseInputs[exerciseInputs.length-1].remove(target);`

***To***

```
$('#' + target).remove();
```

Your updated code can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/oaL2sfme/

Comment: Did the job. Thank you very much. Quick question tho, if I didn't define it, how did you define it? what did you do that made it defined? With kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: 
change your remove function to this:

```
function getRemoveBtnExercise(target, i){
    var RemoveExerciseBtn = $('<a/>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-danger removeBtn'
    }).html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');

    return RemoveExerciseBtn; 
}
```

then because the remove btn is created much later, jquery wont find it dynamically so you have to delegate the event.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeBtn",function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Your resetInput in your fiddle doesnt fire so you could use jquery instead

```
$('#resetInputs').on('click', function ()) {
    location.reload();
});
```